# Paranoid Android Custom Rom For Galaxy s3 i9300 Instructions

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, custom-roms

I want to put paranoid android on my galaxy s3 i9300, **I have tried and been unsuccessful**

Here is the link to where I got the download from;
[XDA Community](http://www.androidfilehost.com/?fid=23501681358558081)

Can someone give me clear instructions as to what exactly I have to do to put this custom rom on my phone please, Thanks

Comment: Did you root your device? Have you installed a custom recovery (Like TWRP or Clockworkmod)? What does 'been unsuccessful' mean specifically, is there errors? Can you please provide more information in your question about what you have done, and what has happened?

Comment: Hi, I rooted my device with superSU, however, I found out that apparently it wasn't necessary
Unsure of what a custom recovery is, could you explain or provide link please

The error was "bad signing key" or something along those lines, can't remember exact words

The steps I followed was wipe phone, root phone, put into recovery mode, wipe phone and cache, install zip  from SD card (i put the Zip file on my external SD card) and when it started installing the error message appears and installation is unsuccessful, Thanks, @RossC

Comment: Ok I've added an answer, hopefully it's all you need, but please do ask questions and I'll modify my answer as we go!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A signature error is often caused by trying to install custom firmware (the ROM) with the stock revovery.  The stock recovery will only install a factory image for the device, signed by the manufacturer. This means you can only install stock firmware with it. So you need a custom recovery, something like Clockworkmod or TWRP recovery.

Note: do at your own risk, and ensure you have the correct device model for this!

**Downloads:**

[This is the link to TWRP for the Galaxy S3.](http://teamw.in/project/twrp2/114)

[This is the link to Clockworkmod (CWM) recovery for Galaxy S3](http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-s3/orig-development/recovery-clockworkmod-touch-6-0-3-2-gt-t1719744)

**How to flash a new recovery with Odin:**

**Step 1: Prepare Odin for Flash**

Make sure Auto Reboot and F. Reset are checked, then click the PDA button and load your .tar file.

**Step 2: Go into Download Mode on Your GS3**

You can do this by powering off your phone, and power back on by holding Volume Down + Home + Power.

If you are on a custom ROM, do **not** do this by holding the Power button, select Reboot, and select Download Mode. It can cause issues in certain models in Odin.

**Step 3: Flash TWRP**

Press the Start button on Odin. Then watch your phone do its thing and reboot.

That's it, you now have the latest and greatest recovery available for the Samsung Galaxy S3.

---

Before installing a new ROM ensure you make a full [nandroid](/questions/tagged/nandroid) backup in your new recovery.

After you install the recovery, boot into it like before, then wipe Cache / Data and install your new ROM.

Comment: Thanks @RossC for the instructions, just to be clear the steps i took to install the rom was correct and should be repeated? and is there a personal preference you have between ClockWorkMod and TWRP? Thanks

Comment: You did everything correct installing the ROM, just via the wrong recovery! They're both very respected recoverys to be honest, and there's not much different. Just read over your ROM and see if they recommend one, you get the odd rare incompatability, but both should be fine! Oh it's worth saying: read the ROM 'how to install' again, and get everything nice and clear before you proceed. Ensure you have a backup or a stock rom you can flash if there are any hiccups. And remember you can install another ROM if P.A. is causing any hassle!

Comment: Thank You, I will let you know how it goes and if I encounter any problems along the way, I appreciate your help!

Comment: Hi @RossC I just put the clockwork mod on my phone and went into recovery mode and it has been successful, When you say make a nandroid backup what choice in the list is that? Also when I clicked to restart my phone it's given me the option to root my device? Should i do it or leave it? Thanks

Comment: Ok, that's all good :) So a nandroid is just a fancy name for a backup for your current system (it backs up EVERYTHING in one, apps, android itself, your rom, your screens, everything). It'll be under 'backup and restore' or similar. You can backup to internal or external SD (good to have one to hand). If it asks to 'retain or keep root' when you reboot, I usually pick yes! Never had an issue! HOWEVER one ROM I used had a warning to pick 'no' so double check P.A. The backup is your "oh god I hate this ROM and everythings all messed up' safety net, you can just flash that in five mins!

Comment: No problem, Thanks, Will let you know when next step is done

Comment: Hi @RossC I have done a backup of the full system, is it best now to go onto my phone and do a factory wipe? or just do a wipe via the CWM? Also i choose the 'backup' option, should i do it to my external sd card so that the factory wipe doesn't erase my backup? Sorry for all the questions, better to be safe than sorry!

Comment: Wipe via CWM is totally fine. Doesn't matter where you backup to the wipe won't remove it! I usually use my external SD, it's slower but I backup to the PC for any disasters, and to keep internal free. Either is fine. It'll go into a folder called Clockworkmod > Backups > Date

Comment: Hi, no problem, I just attempted the Custom Rom after doing my back up and then wiping the phone only on CWM, error message was as follows ;
Error in /sdcard/0/pa_i9300-4.41-20140705.zip (Status 7)
Any suggestions?

Comment: Hi @RossC, Could it be to do with the bootloader being locked? Thanks, Shaun

Comment: Hi @RossC I managed to get it working, I installed a newer version of CWM and it worked fine, Thanks for all your help

Comment: Great! Enjoy the rom, well ROMS plural, once you start you end up trying loads!

Comment: Loved the rom I tried, couldn't be happier, except I couldn't get my gear 2 neo's software (Gear Manager) on there so unfortunately had to resort back to my stock rom, however got a anotherGS3 which I'm putting roms onto to see which is my favourite for future